# convert string into multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, file, numpy

i want to feed my data into a (n,4,5) python numpy array. 
are there any simple solutions?

i've format my data so that each line of the file looks like a python array, but its hard to read it as a python array, for example:

```
[0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0] //line1
[1,0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0] //line2
...
```

desire output:

```
myarray=[[[0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0]]...]
```

seems strip, eval and json all not working well.. please help

i've also tried:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    data = [x.strip() for x in data]
array=[]
for i in data:
    a=split(r'(?<=\]),(?=\[)',i )
    array.append(a)
data=np.array((array))
```

Comment: Please show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap each line in one more pair of brackets, then pass to a suitable eval function:

```
import ast

arr = []
with open('input.txt', 'r') as infp:
    for l in infp:
        arr.append(ast.literal_eval('[%s]' % l))  # replace with eval() if you trust your input data

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]]
```

And a little explanation, as requested:

- Since each line in the input file is of the form `[1,2],[3,4]` and a Python list-of-lists would be `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`, `'[%s]'` is used to wrap the line in that one more pair of brackets to make it valid Python.
- `ast.literal_eval()` is a safe form of `eval()` that only accepts literals (no function calls or other such things).
- So all in all, for a line `[1, 2], [3, 4]`, the effective code is `eval('[[1, 2], [3, 4]]')`.

Comment: it works!! may i ask about 'ast.literal_eval('[%s]' % l)' ?

Comment: @once Added some explanation in the post. Glad I could help!

Answer (score -3):

text = 'a,b,c'

text = text.split(',')

text
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]